# Django and MongoDB - good libraries to use?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

There have been several MongoDB and Django posts - one of the most recent I found was from about 12 months ago. I was wondering what the favourite library/integration method was at the present time and whether anyone had some good pointers about where to look for good ideas?

Thanks,

J

Comment: you mean specifically integrating mongo with Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always run in to this while exploring options Django-mongokit and mongokit on top of pymongo

[Django-Mongokit](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-and-why-to-use-django-mongokit)